# ¿Cómo leer un campo datetime de excel?

Tags: sql, excel

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Exporté una consulta de una tabla a excel, ahora quiero hacer un *INSERT INTO de excel para SQL*, investigando, encontré que el método  más sencillo es este: 
`="INSERT INTO PRUEBA.[dbo].[PRUEBA_INSERT_2] VALUES ('"&A2&"')"`

Mi problema, es que ese campo A2, en SQL, era un datetime, y ahora que estoy creando el script, en lugar de mostrarme el  valor: 27/08/2018 00:00, me muestra: 43339. Sin embargo, si escribo nada más =H2, me muestra la fecha correctamente.

¿Saben que puede estar sucediendo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una cosa el el dato fecha y otra es la representación de la misma como cadena. En está última se hace necesario "formatear" el dato. Puedes hacerlo:

#### 1. Mediante vba/macro

Usando [`format()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

```
"INSERT INTO PRUEBA.[dbo].[PRUEBA_INSERT_2] VALUES ('" & format(A2,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "')"
```

#### 2. Desde una fórmula

Usando [`TEXT()/TEXTO()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)

```
= CONCATENAR("INTO PRUEBA.[dbo].[PRUEBA_INSERT_2]  VALUES ('"; TEXTO(A2;"YYYY/MM/DD");"')")
```

Answer (score 2):

En Excel, las fechas son números enteros. Y las horas, es la parte decimal.

El 1, para Excel, si lo transformas a fechas, equivale a 01/01/1900, el 2 equivale a 02/01/1900y así sucesivamente.

En tu caso, el 43339 equivale a 27/08/2018. Lo que pasa es que tú ves el número normal por el formato de la celda. Cambia el formato de la celda a Fecha y solucionarás tu problema.

Si quieres ver la fecha y hora, tendrás que usar un formato personalizado. Para cambiar el formato de la celda:

1. Clic Derecho en la celda
2. Elige la opción *Formato de Celda*
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde el menú, podrás elegir el formato que quieras. Fecha, o Fecha y hora o si necesitas uno específico, podrás usar la opción de personalizarlo. Por ejemplo, yo quiero ver dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez aplicado el formato, el resultado final que veo en la celda es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.

Comment: Es buena respuesta, pero no cubre del todo el problema original, que es la concatenación de una cadena con una fecha (aparentemente mediante vba).  Se me ocurre que puedes agregar la explicación de la función `format()`. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho. Pues gracias por tu comentario. Acabo de verlo ahora mismo y yo en la pregunta entendí otra cosa, pero tienes toda la razón, la verdad.